Geometric Inequality with Angle Bisectors in a Triangle
Given triangle ABC with angle ABC = 60°.  AP is a bisector of angle BAC. AQ is a bisector of angle CAP.  Prove that BC > 4PQ.
So far, I've managed to express the equality of the products of sides using the Angle Bisector Theorem several times. For example, AB/BP = AC/PC yields (AB)(PC) = (AC)(BP) and we also have equalities like (PC)(AQ) = (AP)(AC). Also, I've considered the three cases: alpha = 15 degrees (easy), alpha < 15 degrees, alpha > 15 degrees. Lastly, using Triangle Inequalities, I've come to 2AP + 2AQ + AB + AC > 3PQ. Maybe Sine or Cosine Laws can help (looks messy), or maybe expanding the diagram to include reflections of lines can help.

Please show us your approach and use MathJax.

@Zhang Are you able to solve it?

@Tan you need to show your efforts first. It'll help us breeze through unnecessary parts that you already know

So far, I've managed to express the equality of the products of sides using the Angle Bisector Theorem several times.  For example, AB/BP = AC/PC yields (AB)(PC) = (AC)(BP) and we also have equalities like (PC)(AQ) = (AP)(AC).
Also, I've considered the three cases: alpha = 15 degrees (easy), alpha < 15 degrees, alpha > 15 degrees.
Lastly, using Triangle Inequalities, I've come to 2AP + 2AQ + AB + AC > 3PQ.
Maybe Sine or Cosine Laws can help (looks messy), or maybe expanding the diagram to include reflections of lines can help.
